# Php exec returns unexpected result while direct call of command in terminal returns correct result (Laravel is used)

Tags: php, ssh

Can't solve the problem.
Briefly: I need to execute command on remote server via ssh.
I have two PCs from where I do that job. Ubuntu server - no problem. But from FreeBSD - problem.
Target server is under Freebsd too.

Access is via ssh keys, user - root. In my client Freebsd I can do `ssh root@x.x.x.x` without any password, so we make conclusion that this part is ok. Next. I run `php artisan tinker` (for those who don't know what is this - this is terminal for executing php code). There I do:

`exec("ssh root@x.x.x.x whoami");`

And I get 'root'. Work is correct. But I do the same via

`dd(exec("ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -v root@x.x.x.x 2>&1"));`

and I get:

`"Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)."`

For that command:

`dd(exec("ssh -v root@91.222.216.24 whoami 2>&1"));`

I get:

`"Host key verification failed."`

As I understand the only way is to use password, but why key auth fails?
How to fix that?

I've tried many options (read many articles on stackoverflow) and in some combination of code I've found that it looks like when command executed via exec another user (www) is used, not root. And I got errors like:

`Could not create directory '/nonexistent/.ssh'.`

As I understand the problem connected to user and its permissions. And it looks like there is no any user at all when sshing via exec.

Upd.

Right in terminal on client PC

`php -r "echo(exec('whoami'));"`

gives. 'root'.

But the same inside of controller in Laravel while using php exec

`dd(exec('whoami'));`

gives 'www'.

For some reasons in php (`exec` command) different user is used.

And yes, in Ubuntu, where I have no problems, I get the same user in both cases (I've checked just now), that's why everything is working there. So,.. the question is How to create ssh keys for another user, which is 'www' or should I change somehow user for php?

Comment: You can tell apache or php fpm which user and group to run as, so at some point the Ubuntu server was probably set to run as root. I'm not sure that's a good idea and wouldn't recommend you change the other server to do the same. I would suggest you simply copy the public key into user www. That to me would be the easiest solution.